Which apps for AOSP distributions display the foreground activity name when viewing other apps?
Rationale
Until I updated my smartphone to Android 14, the most useful answer at "How to get current (foreground) activity name?" - a recommendation to use Current Activity:

Current Activity and some similar apps will display the info in the form of floating texts above the screen content.

...was rendered outdated, due to API change.
To bypass this, I've successfully requested that a developer add this functionality to their application. However, I don't know when the next compilation shall occur.
Request
In the meantime, do any alternative applications provide this functionality for AOSP 14+? Unlike the aforereferenced question, I solely request software recommendations, (instead of alternative methods to achieve this, like the CLI commands mentioned in my answer to that question).

CLI answers are available at https://android.stackexchange.com/q/185720/311449.

I have combined my answers into one, because solely one of the options presented is actually of worth to the majority of users.
Recommendations
As this GitHub comment from the developer of an activity manager application for AOSP 14 explains, this should be available in all versions > 3.1.7.

Implemented in 45ff4f8.

I shall update and accept this answer when the exact version is released.
Redundant
Current Activity provides similar functionality. However, it doesn't function on AOSP >= 14.
